# Generate HTML file with Powershell

Tags: html, css, powershell

I need help !

Currently, I fill a string with HTML code via a powershell script and then i write it in a file index.html

However, when I display the index.html file in question, the css file is not loaded, regardless of the modifications I make.

On the other hand, if I create a new index.html file and copy/paste the content of the old file into the new one, then everything works.

Anyone know why?

Comment: There must be an issue in your powershell script.

Comment: One thing to check is the encoding.  There may be some encodings that simply do not work with a browser.  Copying something to the clipboard and then pasting it into an existing file gets around the encoding problem.  Try encoding as ASCII.

Comment: How are you writing the information to the file? Please post a sample of your code and  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example